# Correct way of storing __m128 in an array/vector, to iterate without having to load/store from/to scalar float

Tags: c++, performance, containers, simd, intrinsics

**Summary of the question:**

In C++, I am trying to find out the best way to store `__m128` variables in containers such as `array` or `std::vector`, in order to iterate without having to call the expensive `_mm_load_ps` or `_mm_store_ps`.

---

**Long version of the question:**

A common way to iterate over a container of floating-point numbers using SIMD SSE2 intrinsics functions in C++ looks like this:

```
std::vector<float> X1[N];
std::vector<float> X2[N];
std::vector<float> Y[N];

// any code to fill X1 and X2 with float scalar values

for(int i=0; i<N; i+=4)
{
    __m128 _x1 = _mm_load_ps(&X1[i]);
    __m128 _x2 = _mm_load_ps(&X2[i]);
    __m128 _sum = _mm_add_ps(_x1, _x2);
    __m128 _sqrt = _mm_sqrt_ps(_sum);
    _mm_store_ps(&Y[i], _sum);
}
```

In general, if `N` is not very small the "pseudo-C++ code" above would yield already a significant performance boost over the initial scalar implementation (assuming of course that the compiler is not converting it automatically into a SIMD-vectorized code).

However, if the two `_mm_load_ps` calls and the one `_mm_store_ps` calls could be avoided, that would improve performance quite a bit further. In the example above, that would mean, of course, saving the input data already in `__m128` variables.

What I don't quite get is what is the best way of achieving that. My first intuition was that we could just use something like `std::vector<__m128> X1(N)` or even like a static array of type `__m128 X1[N]`. Then, we could just iterate over such containers, retrieve each `__m128` at the position `j` within each container and directly apply the calculations. Something like the following:

```
std::vector<__m128> X1v[N];
std::vector<__m128> X2v[N];
std::vector<__m128> Yv[N];

// any code to fill X1 and X2 with float SIMD vectors

for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
{
    __m128 _sum = _mm_add_ps(X1[j], X2[j]);
    Y[j] = _mm_sqrt_ps(_sum);
}
```

I tried implementing exactly that, but to my surprise, it ended resulting in either roughly the same performance time of the previous SIMD code above, or often in even slower performance. So, I am trying to understand both:

1) why is the reason for that? I was expecting a relevant performance improvement since no loads/stores are done anywhere in the loop (which is the part of the code that matters to me performance-wise). Did I do something wrong in my example-implementation (see the code below)?

2) what is the correct way of using containers of `__m128` in order to avoid loads and stores from scalar to vector and then back to scalar, in case one want to iterate over a high number of values and can operate with vectorized data directly?

Here it is my real-code implementation, already doing the performance measurement:

```
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int N = 100000;
__declspec(align(16)) vector<float> X1;
__declspec(align(16)) vector<float> X2;
__declspec(align(16)) vector<float> Y(N);

__declspec(align(16)) vector<__m128> X1v;
__declspec(align(16)) vector<__m128> X2v;
__declspec(align(16)) vector<__m128> Yv(N / 4);

int main() {

    default_random_engine randomGenerator(time(0));
    uniform_real_distribution<float> diceroll(0.0f, 100.0f);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) X1.push_back(diceroll(randomGenerator));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) X2.push_back(diceroll(randomGenerator));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 4)
    {
        __m128 _x1v = _mm_loadu_ps(&X1[i]);
        __m128 _x2v = _mm_loadu_ps(&X2[i]);
        X1v.push_back(_x1v);
        X2v.push_back(_x2v);
    }

    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point c1start, c1end, c2start, c2end;

    c1start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i += 4)
    {
        __m128 _x1 = _mm_load_ps(&X1[i]);
        __m128 _x2 = _mm_load_ps(&X2[i]);
        __m128 _sum = _mm_add_ps(_x1, _x2);
        __m128 _sqrt = _mm_sqrt_ps(_sum);
        _mm_store_ps(&Y[i], _sqrt);
    }
    c1end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    c2start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int j = 0; j<(N / 4); j++)
    {
        __m128 _x1 = X1v[j];
        __m128 _x2 = X2v[j];
        __m128 _sum = _mm_add_ps(_x1, _x2);
        __m128 _sqrt = _mm_sqrt_ps(_sum);
        Yv[j] = _sqrt;
    }
    c2end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


    auto c1 = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(c1end - c1start).count();
    auto c2 = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(c2end - c2start).count();

    cout << "With arrays of floats and loads/stores: " << (float)c1 << endl;
    cout << "With arrays of __m128 and no loads or stores: " << (float)c2 << endl;
    cout << "Ratio arrays-of-m128: / arrays-of-floats " << (float)c2 / (float)c1 << endl;

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you look at the compiled code, you'll find that `_mm_load_ps` and `_mm_store_ps` compile to load and store instructions. If you're trying to read/write from an `std::vector`, you're going to need to load/store anyway. So in that sense, those intrinsics aren't expensive. On the other hand, you have a bigger problem. Aligning the vector object doesn't align the elements. There's no way to align the objects unless you specify your own allocator.

Comment: @Mysticial Thanks for the comment. About the aligning, sure: I was in the middle of the process of implementing a custom allocator, when I noticed what I've asked in the question. About the store/load: if I understood correctly, what you say is that the operations of including/retrieving elements to/from *any* container in C++ boils down to the save store/load assembly commands that are used to include/retrieve `float` into `__m128`? Or is this only the case of `std::vector`, in which case there would be ways to achieve what I described?

Comment: After compiler optimizations and everything, the (aligned) load/store intrinsics are no different from assignments . If it needs to be loaded or stored, the compiler will issue the necessary load/store instructions. If it's just a register copy, the compiler will do just that. I'm basically saying that the normal load/store intrinsics are useless other than as a form of self-documenting code to make it explicit to the reader that you're trying to load/store.